# New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, flag-dialog, flag-reasons

We've changed the flagging format from today(AFAIK) as below,

> [image]

looks good.

But, when I select *it should be closed for another reason...*

I can see the same reason duplicate on the top.

> [image]

What is the need of placing that reason over there?
It should not be there. Please remove the dupe.

Comment: Both of them are disabled once you use any of them (confirmed).

Comment: @AzizShaikh, it functions correctly, but there is no need to show the *duplicate of* reason in the closing for another reason.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, they probably left it there for users who are really used to have it in that exact place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, removed bug tag.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the "breadcrumbs" at the top, you'll see the top-level "it is a duplicate..." is just a shortcut to the same dialogue.

> Flagging > Closing > Duplicate

Answer (score 5):

Without official response telling us the real motive, I'll share my own opinion, based on my experience on this place, and  on Stack Exchange in general.

As I see it, duplicates are special case. They are not off topic like all other close reasons, on the contrary: duplicate question is on topic, and many times a good question on its own.

So it totally deserves a place of its own in the flag/close reason list.

As for why it's also in the "should be closed for another reason" list, couple of reasons:

- Historical: users who are used to find it there won't have to go look for it elsewhere.
- Being the main close reason (e.g. 23 out of 50 recently [closed questions on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3a1)), having it "featured" in more than one place cause less chance that users will miss it when flagging. Redundancy can be good sometimes.